# MS Access (365) Forms: One ID links to two fields (primary, secondary). How can I get a subform to retrieve both fields?

Tags: microsoft-access, forms

I have a company table and a contractor table.  The contractor table has a primary contractor and secondary contractor field.  Both fields pull a company name from the company table.

I've created a Company form with a Contracts subform.  The purpose is to assign a contract(s) when I'm adding a new company. The issue I am facing is when I add companies.contractor AND companies_1.contractor to the Contracts subform, companies_1.contractor saves as companies.contractor.  I've tried to drag and drop the field as well as type the appropriate name in the "Control Source" field in the Property Sheet.  Neither served as a solution.  It keeps saving as companies.contractor instead of companies_1.contractor.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening so I can capture data for both my primary and secondary company instead of showing only the secondary contract information (companies.contractor is secondary in my database)?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to Form Properties and update Record Source.

Instead of using the query I created that housed all the data in one view, I created the relationships between 2 tables, which will appear as 3 tables in the relationship/query creator view (companies, contracts, companies_1).  PrimeContractorID would link to CompanyID in Companies_1 table and CompanyID would link to CompanyID in Companies table.